# Given a Name and Height table, how would you output a table which has the average height of the people whose names start with that letter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have a table with Alice, Ahmed, Bob and Coady, with their respective heights being 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4 respectively. I would like the output to be A: 1.15, B: 1.3, and C:1.4, and when I add in a new person called Dumbo who is 1.5, there should be a new row in the output D:1.5. I am a bit new to SQL, but it seems like you probably have to loop through all elements in the name to extract the first letter, group them together, and then make another query to pull out the average values?

Is there also an easy way to output this, but this time showing all the letters of the alphabet, and having height = 0 if there is no entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT avg(height), first_letter FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(names, 1, 1) AS first_letter, height FROM table_name) AS names GROUP BY first_letter;
```